# Hover of nesting elements and position sticky element issue

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table with horizontal scrolling and when hover on the line I want hover whole row. I've made it using vertical divs because I have some background image on the first column.

I have an issue when hovering element span, red-line disappeared and 2nd issue is red-line is not visible on first column which is position fixed for scrolling.

**CSS**:

```
.table {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: aqua;
}

.table-column {
  width: 33%
}

.table-cell {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  min-width: 220px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  z-index: 1;
}

.red-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff4a4a;
  right: -5%;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.table-column:first-child {
  z-index: 3;
  background-image: url('https://wallpaper.dog/large/20616186.jpg');
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.table-cell:hover .red-line,
.table-cell span:hover+.red-line {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>1 sticky</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>2 sticky</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>3 sticky</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-column">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>1</span>
      <div class="red-line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>2</span>
      <div class="red-line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <span>3</span>
      <div class="red-line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```